# Why is my image style's applied to all images when I've specifically styled each?

Tags: html, css

I need "tumbnail.jpg" , "child.png" and "nanny.png" to be in square shape.
also "tumbnail.jpg" as a thumbnail. (It's already a thumbnail I guess)
other two I need them as just squared images side by side. Please help me with this. I tried to solve this since 4 days but I couldn't.
how should I style those 3 to be squared?

```css
body { background-image: url( "bg.jpg" ); }
h2, p { text-align: center; }
.lulu{font-family:Copperplate, Papyrus, fantasy;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bolder;
}

.parent{ background-color:lightgrey;
width: 80%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height:200px;}


.column {
float: left;
width: 30%;
padding: 5px;
}


.child-1{
background-color:lightgray;
width:73%;
float:center;
height:900px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:50px;
padding-bottom:50px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-left:50px;
margin-left:130px;
margin-right:150px;
margin-top:80px;
margin-bottom:80px;
}

.child-1 p {
color: white;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top: 50px;
text-align:center;
width:80%;}

.child-2{
background-color:aliceblue;
width:300px;
float:right;
height:400px;
margin:50px;
text-align:left;
padding-left:10px;}

.child-2 p{
color: black; 
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top: 50px;
text-align:left;
width:80%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=styles.css>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Daycare Center</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<div class="parent">

<header>
<h1 class="lulu"> DAYCARE</h1>
</header>

<style>
img {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:2px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width:auto;
  max-height:auto;
  display: block; 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
<img src="tumbnail.jpg" alt="kids" style="width:100px" style="height:100px">
</div>


<div>
<div class="child-1">

<h3 style="color:white;">
Child care: Making the best choice 
for your family</h3>

<p>.</p>


<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
<style>
img {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width:auto;
  max-height:auto;
 }
</style>
    <img src="house.jpg" alt="house" style="width:100px" style="height:100px">
  </div>


  <div class="column">
<style>
img {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width:auto;
  max-height:auto;
}
</style>
    <img src="heart.jpg" alt="heart" style="width:100px" style="height:100px">
  </div>

  <div class="column">
<style>
img {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width:auto;
  max-height:auto;
  }
</style>
    <img src="feet.jpg" alt="feet" style="width:100px" style="height:100px">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="child.png" alt="child" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="nanny.png" alt="nanny" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>


<div>
<div style="position:relative; right:8px; top:90px;">
<div class="child-2">


<h3>About us:</h3>
<p>.</p>

<h3>Our Service</h3>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>

<main>

<section>

</section>

</main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not how CSS cascades, you can't insert a `<style>` tag and only style elements after it in the DOM. If you want to steal each image individually, give each one an ID or a class, and use a selector to apply styles like you do for you other elements.

Comment: The creation of a few <style> tags for every element is bad practice, anyway. Just use one styles section or move all styles to a particular stylesheet like a styles.css. Then for applying a particular style for every image, use classes for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not ideal to use several differant styling options on one page.
It is recommened that all styling is maintained seperately from your pages code.

e.g by using a css.

Using the `img` tag in your css will affect ALL img tags  in your code.

If you want to add additional specific changes to certain images then you should add a class e.g

```
<img class="fill"/>

.fill {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

### SPECIFICITY

If an item in your css is after a conflicting class the subsequent one will take priority as long as the element doesn't have a more dominat identifier.

You can read more about that here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

For this example, having `.fill` after img will cause this image to be width and height **100%** rather than **100px**

**EXAMPLE**

```css
img {
  background:#cdf;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.fill {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxBTo.png">
<img class="fill" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxBTo.png">
```

---

I recommend you clear the styling from your html and add it to your css.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
}

h2,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.lulu {
  font-family: Copperplate, Papyrus, fantasy;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.parent {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.child-1 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 73%;
  float: center;
  height: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.child-1 p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

.child-2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.child-2 p {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="parent">
    <header>
      <h1 class="lulu"> DAYCARE</h1>
    </header>
    <img src="tumbnail.jpg" alt="kids">
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="child-1">

      <h3 style="color:white;">Child care: Making the best choice for your family</h3>

      <p>.</p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="house.jpg" alt="house">
        </div>


        <div class="column">
          <img src="heart.jpg" alt="heart">
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <img src="feet.jpg" alt="feet">
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <img src="child.png" alt="child" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img src="nanny.png" alt="nanny" style="width:100%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="child-2">

              <h3>About us:</h3>
              <p>.</p>

              <h3>Our Service</h3>
              <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>

          <main>

            <section>

            </section>

          </main>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```